# Matchstick game in Prolog

Tags: prolog, puzzle

I need to come up with some way to solve this problem in prolog :

[image: this is the game]
[image: here is the solution]

We've got some trash and a dustpan made of matchsticks. You need to only move two matchsticks to change the picture so the dustpan is no longer holding the trash. (As you can see in the pictures, what I'm trying to do is the opposite, we have the dustpan with trash in it to begin with)

I still haven't figured out how to represent the dustpan, i was thinking maybe with a matrix, something like this:

```
R = [ [0,1,0,1,0], 
      [0,1,8,1,0], 
      [0,1,1,1,0], 
      [0,0,1,0,0], 
      [0,0,1,0,0] ].
```

But, in trying to program it i cant figure out how to do it.

Can you guys help me ?

Comment: Is this the required imput? Because you lose information like how are the matches oriented... And what do you want to program? A checker, solver,...

Comment: i need to program a solver, do you have any suggestions on how to represent the problem? cause that would be great!

Comment: You need to describe the problem in words first. I don't see any description regarding what are considered legal match moves, or whether the direction of the matches matters, etc. Once you can describe it precisely, then you can determine a representation and suitable set of rules.

Comment: There are no legal match moves or rules, the only thing is that you can only move two matchsticks, you can move them wherever / however you like, but you can only move two and the shape has to be the same, the dustpan has to be a dustpan everytime you move two matchsticks.  @lurker

Comment: Maybe a matrix is not the best way to go. Maybe you should define the matches with the endpoints, and place arithmetic restrictions on the coordinates based on the thrash's position, and each other. Then you start to find all possible solutions and see if there is one where only two matchsticks differ... I would definitely do that, and use CLP for the arithmetic restrictions.